# var/www/folder Files for download

Tags: web, download, var

How to do it img, exe, cmd, bat, mp3, css, php, html, png, jpg, gif files for downloaded

For example

var/www/file/document.cmd

download link www.adress.com/file/document.cmd

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7VHR.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w51VP.png)

Comment: That are executable files and some images, what is your point?

Comment: How to do this?

Comment: How to do what?

Comment: sudo chmod 755 /var/www/folderNameToDownload To make the items inside the folder downloadable

Comment: We are here to help with coding related questions, not make the code for you. We don't even know what language you are using. Take a step back from the question and do the following: research how to make files in your programming languages, try and code your functionality and if then if you've tried but your code isn't working you can ask your question.

Answer (score 1):

sudo chmod 755 /var/www/folderNameToDownload To make the items inside the folder downloadable

You can see about permissions in linux [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/File_permissions_and_attributes) . In this document under numeric method you can find how it works.

```
r(ead)=4
w(rite)=2
x(executable)=1

Owner: rwx=4+2+1=7
Group: r-x=4+0+1=5
Other: r-x=4+0+1=5
```

so by providing chmod 755 we are giving alrights to owner and restricting writing rights to group and others. Hope it helps